# Function replace on partial word, how to get to replace on whole words only Google script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, replace

I have a function that finds and replaces from an array of Find Replace values.

as configured, it replaces partial wards

I need to Replace on `whole` word only.

How to replace whole words only?

```
function test_n() {
let  arr= [
 [ 'Collins, Matthew James'],
 [ 'Collins, Matthew'],
 [ 'Collins, Matthew J'],
 [ 'Collins, M. J.'],
 [ 'Collins, M.J.'],
 [ 'Collins, M.'],
 [ 'Collins, M.J'],
 [ 'Collins, M'],
 [ 'Collins, M J']
]

 let RgX = [
 [ 'Collins, Matthew James', 'Collins, Matthew' ],
 [ 'Collins, Matthew', 'Collins, Matthew' ],
 [ 'Collins, Matthew J', 'Collins, Matthew' ],
 [ 'Collins, M. J.', 'Collins, Matthew' ],
 [ 'Collins, M.J.', 'Collins, Matthew' ],
 [ 'Collins, M.', 'Collins, Matthew' ],
 [ 'Collins, M.J', 'Collins, Matthew' ],
 [ 'Collins, M', 'Collins, Matthew' ],
 [ 'Collins, M J', 'Collins, Matthew' ]
]

//RgX[0] =to_replace value
//RgX[1] = replace_with value

arr = processValues(arr, RgX)
console.log(arr)
}


function processValues(values, replaceTable) {
  //let replaceTable = RgX;
  return values.map(row =>
    row.map(c => c 
     ? replaceTable.reduce(
       (curString, tableEntry) => curString.replaceAll(...tableEntry)
       , c) : '', ""));
}
```

I get the result

```
[ [ 'Collins, Matthewatthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthewatthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthewatthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthewatthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthewatthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthewatthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, MatthewatthewJ' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew J' ] ]
```

What I need is

```
[ [ 'Collins, Matthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew' ],
  [ 'Collins, Matthew' ] ]
```

I have tried changing this.

`(curString, tableEntry) => curString.replaceAll(...tableEntry)` to `(curString, tableEntry) => curString.replaceAll(new RegExp('\\b' + tableEntry[0] + '//b','g'),tableEntry[1])`

but this substitution does not affect the output; output = input

Comment: You might find it easier to use `textFinder`

Comment: I thought textFinder only worked on ranges, not arrays

Comment: You wanted `'\\b'`, not `'//b'`.

Comment: Why not write a single pattern `.*\bCollins, (?:Matthew(?: James)?\b|M\.?(?: ?J\.?)?)(?!\S).*` and replace with `Collins, Matthew` https://regex101.com/r/fZ5bt9/1

Comment: So I fixed the incorrect `'//b'`  but this still fails for All entries that end in a `.` Ex: `'Collins, Matthew J.` it gives back `'Collins, Matthew J'`

Comment: The fourth bird, Matthew, is just one name variation of many so I need a general solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `processValues` function with:

```
function processValues(values, replaceTable) {
  return values.map(name => replaceTable.find(
    fromTo => fromTo[0] == name
  )).map(fromTo => fromTo ? fromTo[1] : undefined);
}
```

Notes:

- `.find()` finds the name in the table, and returns the `fromTo` array
- the second `.map()` changes the `fromTo` array to the "to" value